# CSS margin adding on UL tag

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm coding  a responsive site using 996px framework. Can any one clear up an issue I'm having?

When I use a `<ul>` tag  the browser is adding default margin on the left, 40px;

Please see below the css

```
 display: block;
 list-style-type: disc;
 -webkit-margin-before: 1em; 
 -webkit-margin-after: 1em; 
 -webkit-margin-start: 0px;  
 -webkit-margin-end: 0px; 
 -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Can _you_ shed some light on this? What are you selecting? What do you mean by use a tag?

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: Try to use a [CSS Reseter](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: It may surprise you, but browsers have default styles for a lot of elements.  If you don't like the default styles, override them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalize.css comes with the ul padding of 40px left, You just add `ul,ol,dl{margin:0 auto; padding:0}`for resetting all lists.

Answer (score 2):

Part of [`normalize.css`](http://996grid.com/css/normalize.css) in the 996grid framework has this style declaration:

```
menu,
ol,
ul {
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}
```

If you don't want it, you have to explicitly remove it. Just add a `padding:0` declaration to your styles for the particular element.

You also seem to be using `-webkit-padding-start: 40px;`, which is of course going to affect padding as well...